# Toggling Radio Buttons In WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

This is what I'm doing and it results in a stack overflow because it just switches back and forth forever.

```
    private void radioButtonA_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButtonB.Checked = !radioButtonB.Checked;
    }

    private void radioButtonB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButtonA.Checked = !radioButtonA.Checked;
    }
```

There has to be a better way to do this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try commenting out all of your code and see if it works the way you want.
you don't have to uncheck the other radio buttons in code

Answer (score 4):

Is it toggling of "One" radio button what you were trying to do? If so, I tried this, and it works for me:

Set the Radio Button AutoCheck property to FALSE.

Create a "Click" event for the Radio Button.

In the Click Event Handler for the Radio Button paste the code:

radioButton.Checked = !radioButton.Checked;

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Event in the code before changing the Checked value, then add it again immediately afterwards.